# Reference: Hölder regularity for linear elliptic equation, Neumann problem

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I checked the Book of Gilbarg Trudinger on elliptic equations for (Hölder)-regularity results on weak solutions for elliptic pde.

In particular, my equation is of the form $$\nabla \cdot (\kappa(x)\nabla p + \gamma(x))= 0$$
with "good" functions $\kappa$ and $\gamma$. In the book only the Dirichlet case is treated (in chapter 8). In the remarks on the chapter one finds that an extension of the result to mixed boundary value problems is possible as long as one maintains a small "Dirichlet"-part. As the title suggests I'm interested in a fully Neumann problem. In a different text the required result is referred to as "standard elliptic" theory. But I did not find it yet.  Does anyone know an additional reference or did I misread Gilbarg Trudinger?

Of course I'm considering bounded domains :)

Comment: Is $\kappa$ a scalar- or matrix-valued function here?  Also, as written it appears that $-\nabla \cdot \gamma$ is just playing the role of a charge density?

Comment: $\kappa$ is a matrix and $\gamma(x)$ is a vector that could describe gravity (that's how i consider the equation). With the divergence it could also be considered as charge density. $\kappa$ is (of course) uniformly elliptic. And

Comment: Well, if you're going to have a fully Neumann problem, you're going to have a compatibility condition. If that condition is satisfied, then you should be good to go. What kind of results are you interested in extending? Existence, uniqueness (this may require some sort of averaging condition to get rid of constants), regularity?

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot the compatibility conditions. I'm having zero average of $p$ and of the Neumann-data. I already know that a solution exists.

Comment: But should this really matter if I already have a solution?

Comment: So, just to check, it's the regularity results you want?

Comment: yes, I've give a weak solution say in $H^1(\Omega)$. I have the "right" regularity for the coefficients (Hölder continuous) and wand $p$ to be Hölder continuous and later I will also need that $\nabla p$ is Hölder. For the Dirichlet case there are well known results. But not for the Neumann case. As far as I know the proof for the Neumann case will require a reflection argument.